# Possible to bind keyup to entire form?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, onkeyup

Is it possible to bind `keyup()` to an entire `<form>`? For example, I have multiple `<input type="text">` fields inside a form, and I want to bind a `keyup` event to all of them without having to attach a `keyup` event handler to each one. Rather, I want to bind one `keyup` event handler to all of them so if any of the text fields detect a `keyup` event, the event handler will run. Is this possible in jQuery?

I tried:

```
$('form').keyup(function() {...});
```

But that made the keyup event handler fire indefinitely after typing one character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, but you are able to bind the same `keyup` event to all the inputs at once:

```
$('#myform input[type=text]').on('keyup', /* yada */);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try something Like this: [**Fast Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/shlomohassid/Bc4wK/)

```
$(function(){
   //create one instance for handler:
   var myHandler = function(e){ /* Your function */ };

   //Bind it:
   $("#form input[type=text]").on('keyup',function(e){ myHandler(e);  });

});
```

Comment: Why wrapping the function in yet another function?

Comment: @TimWolla `$(function() {...})` is the same as `$(document).ready(function() {...})`

Comment: @ShlomiHassid I am not talking about that `jQuery(document).ready` one, but the additional one in you `on` function.

Comment: @JasonP I am aware of that, see my reply to Shlomi.

Comment: He may want to do something specific for any input field - and the most important is for catching the event for later use such as `e.keyCode` without it you cant pass the event...